# Can't enter a tab character when previous character is not a tab or space in insert mode

Tags: neovim, tab-characters

When pressing `tab` in any language in edit mode, nothing happens if the character before the cursor is not a space or a tab.
Doing `ctrl-v tab` works, but I don't want to have to do that every time and presumably it would cause some problems if I rebind `tab` to that.

When doing `nvim --clean`, I have no problems, but before I uninstall every plugin and start from the top, does anyone know which plugin or piece of config may be causing this?

Config:

https://github.com/pseud0n/nixos-config/blob/main/home-manager/home.nix#L205

https://github.com/pseud0n/nixos-config/blob/main/home-manager/config/nvim/init.vim

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604 and `:verbose set expandtab?`, perhaps

Comment: Does `:imap <Tab>` show a mapping for Tab in Insert mode?

Comment: Looks like it's the mapping from line 262 of your init.vim, which is triggering `coc#refresh()` on tab, unless on a pop-up menu or when preceded by whitespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Completion-with-sources#improve & https://bleepcoder.com/coc-nvim/421789422/issue-on-pressing-tab-at-the-end-of-a-word, a better version without this problem:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"

function! s:check_back_space() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```

Comment: You should probably show the `check_back_space` definition to make the answer complete

Comment: Also, the posted code sets two mappings for tab—the second will completely override the first?